# XML - Deserialize into object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, api

I am trying to deserialize a API response into an object but the object keeps returning NULL. I can't figure it out. I feel like I'm missing something minor.

Here the c# deserialize code.

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri + data);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE = null;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE));


        PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE = (PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
```

this is the XML response from the API.

```
<PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
<STATUS>
    <CODE>1</CODE>
    <VIEW>ERROR</VIEW>
    <ERRORTYPE>INPUT_ERROR</ERRORTYPE>
    <MESSAGE>Testing Mode: You have passed input validation, the pickup request has NOT been submitted</MESSAGE>
    <VERSION>
        <CURRENT>V3X1</CURRENT>
        <CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE>03/01/2014</CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE>
        <LATEST>V3X1</LATEST>
        <LATEST_RELEASE_DATE>03/01/2014</LATEST_RELEASE_DATE>
    </VERSION>
</STATUS>
</PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE>
```

here is the c# object I've created.

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE")]
public class PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE
{
    [XmlArray("PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE")]
    [XmlArrayItem("STATUS", typeof(STATUS))]
    public STATUS[] STATUS { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
public class STATUS
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string CODE { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("VIEW")]
    public string VIEW { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ERRORTYPE")]
    public string ERRORTYPE { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MESSAGE")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("VERSION", typeof(VERSION))]
    public VERSION[] VERSION { get; set; }

}

[Serializable()]
public class VERSION
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CURRENT")]
    public string CURRENT { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE")]
    public string CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LATEST")]
    public string LATEST { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LATEST_RELEASE_DATE")]
    public string LATEST_RELEASE_DATE { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: The escaped `\"` look strange to me, I doubt you´ll need those, just use `="..."`.

Comment: Dude, those variable names are horrible. Learn some naming conventions

Comment: hey, this is a judgement free zone on variable names. To each their own.

Comment: Where are you referring to @HimBromBeere ? Edit: Are you referring to the XML response? I have no control on how the API responds.

Comment: On your declaration of the root-tag. Where you reference the schema and the `xsi`. Btw.: What @Eric mentions is true, conventions exist to improve understanding and thus maintainability of your code. Of course you *could* name your variables as you want but it´s not recommended to do so, in particular when more than just one developer is involved.

Comment: I was joking, this is just a test harness I built to test the API. This is not going into production with these variable names. @HimBromBeere

Comment: No offence mate, it just makes it hard to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data Contracts are constructed in the wrong way

```
public class PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE
{
    [XmlArray("PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE")]
    [XmlArrayItem("STATUS", typeof(STATUS))]
    public STATUS[] STATUS { get; set; }
}
```

This would assume your xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE>
    ...
```

The same goes for `VERSION`. By specifying XmlArray and XmlArrayItem it will expect nested instances of the elements which your sample xml didn't have.

The objects below should work

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE")]
public class PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE
{
    //[XmlArray("PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE")]
    //[XmlArrayItem("STATUS", typeof(STATUS))]
    [XmlElement("STATUS")]
    public STATUS[] STATUS { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
public class STATUS
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string CODE { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("VIEW")]
    public string VIEW { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ERRORTYPE")]
    public string ERRORTYPE { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MESSAGE")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }

    //[XmlArrayItem("VERSION", typeof(VERSION))]
    [XmlElement("VERSION")]
    public VERSION[] VERSION { get; set; }

}

[Serializable()]
public class VERSION
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CURRENT")]
    public string CURRENT { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE")]
    public string CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LATEST")]
    public string LATEST { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LATEST_RELEASE_DATE")]
    public string LATEST_RELEASE_DATE { get; set; }

}
```

I also recommend using a standard pattern for xml serialization, something like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserialize an xml string to type T
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="xml"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        return default(T);

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    // No settings need modifying here

    using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke it like this

```
var resp = Deserialize<PICKUPREQUESTRESPONSE>(thexml);
```